# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'voiceID' does not exist

Tags: android

This is the error message:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'voiceID' does not exist

It says that the column doesn't exist but it's in the create statement. The activity won't even open. I'm using Android Studio and Sqlite to make an app with a database. I've attached the classes. This is the Database Helper.

```
public class ContactDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TAG = ContactDBHelper.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cally.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public ContactDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String SQL_CREATE_STATEMENT = "CREATE TABLE " + ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + ContactEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + ContactEntry.COLUMN_VOICE_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ContactEntry.COLUMN_VIDEO_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_IMAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_STATEMENT);
    Log.v(TAG,"Table Created");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

This is the Contract class:

```
public final class Contract {

private Contract(){}

public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.cally";
public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);
public static final String PATH_CONTACTS = "Contacts";

public static final class ContactEntry implements BaseColumns{

    public static final String CONTENT_LIST_TYPE =
            ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_CONTACTS;


    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
            ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_CONTACTS;


    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT_URI, PATH_CONTACTS);

    public final static String TABLE_NAME = "Contacts";
    public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public final static String COLUMN_VOICE_ID = "voiceID";
    public final static String COLUMN_VIDEO_ID = "videoID";
    public final static String COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME = "name";
    public final static String COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER = "number";
    public final static String COLUMN_CONTACT_IMAGE = "imagePath";


}


}
```

The is the Main Activity, the insert data is to insert dummy data.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FloatingActionButton FAB;
    private String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ContactDBHelper mDBHelper;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FAB = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewContact.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        mDBHelper = new ContactDBHelper(this);

    }

    private void insertContact() {
        // Gets the database in write mode
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();



        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((999 - 1) + 1) + 1;

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ContactEntry._ID,randomNum);
        values.put(ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME, "Bob");
        values.put(ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER, "1234567");
        values.put(ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_IMAGE,"bob.jpg");
        values.put(ContactEntry.COLUMN_VOICE_ID, "4472");
        values.put(ContactEntry.COLUMN_VIDEO_ID, "4471");

//        long newRowId = db.insert(ContactEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);


        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(ContactEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
        displayInfo();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        displayInfo();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_insert_dummy_data:
                insertContact();

                displayInfo();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void displayInfo() {
        // Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
        // you will actually use after this query.
        String[] projection = {
                ContactEntry._ID,
                ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME,
                ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER,
                ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_IMAGE};

        // Perform a query on the provider using the ContentResolver.
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // The content URI of the words table
                projection,             // The columns to return for each row
                null,                   // Selection criteria
                null,                   // Selection criteria
                null);                  // The sort order for the returned rows

        TextView displayView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tableCount);

        try {
            // Create a header in the Text View that looks like this:
            //
            //
            // In the while loop below, iterate through the rows of the cursor and display
            // the information from each column in this order.
            displayView.setText("The contacts table contains " + cursor.getCount() + " contacts.\n\n");

            displayView.append(ContactEntry._ID + " - " +
                    ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME + " - " +
                    ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER + " - " +
                    ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_IMAGE + "\n" +
                    ContactEntry.COLUMN_VOICE_ID + " - " +
                    ContactEntry.COLUMN_VIDEO_ID + "\n");

            // Figure out the index of each column
            int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry._ID);
            int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME);
            int numberColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER);
            int imageColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_IMAGE);
            int voiceIDColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactEntry.COLUMN_VOICE_ID);
            int videoIDColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry.COLUMN_VIDEO_ID);

            // Iterate through all the returned rows in the cursor
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Use that index to extract the String or Int value of the word
                // at the current row the cursor is on.
                int currentID = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
                String currentName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
                String currentNumber = cursor.getString(numberColumnIndex);
                String currentImage = cursor.getString(imageColumnIndex);
                String currentVoiceID = cursor.getString(voiceIDColumnIndex);
                String currentVideoID = cursor.getString(videoIDColumnIndex);
                // Display the values from each column of the current row in the cursor in the TextView
                displayView.append(("\n" + currentID + " - " +
                        currentName + " - " +
                        currentNumber + " - " +
                        currentImage + " - " +
                        currentVoiceID + " - " +
                        currentVideoID));
            }
        } finally {
            // Always close the cursor when you're done reading from it. This releases all its
            // resources and makes it invalid.
            cursor.close();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Which line gives you this error? Can you post the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
String[] projection = {
            ContactEntry._ID,
            ContactEntry.COLUMN_VOICE_ID,
            ContactEntry.COLUMN_VIDEO_ID,
            ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME,
            ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER,
            ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_IMAGE};
```